# Makefile - include path in separate file

Tags: c, makefile

I would like to store all paths to headers in separate file. I'm going to generate file with paths dynamically, to avoid re-creating Makefile whenever paths change.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can generate the file, let's call it `paths.inc`, so it looks like, for example:

```
INCLUDEPATH=path1:path2
```

and then include the file in your main `Makefile`

```
include paths.inc
```

and use the variable defined in it: `${INCLUDEPATH}`

Answer (score 2):

### Makefile

```
paths_mk := paths.mk
-include $(paths_mk)
$(paths_mk) :
    # Rule to generate paths.mk

include_flags = $(include_paths:%=-I%)

CPPFLAGS += $(include_flags)

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

### paths.mk

```
# Auto-generated file.
include_paths := ...
```